# How to disable view caching in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

We am using ionic 3 with d3js. We have lot of d3.js transitions in each component (which we believe takes lot of memory). 
App responds quickly(fast) to navigation and content rendering initially however after navigating 5-10 pages, app gets slower. We see lag in page navigations and content rendering. 
We believe this is because of view caching in iconic 3 (not sure if view caching is enabled in iconic 3).

When user clicks on navigation buttons, we push or pop from NavController.
Is there way to disable view caching so that app performance is same irrespective of how many times user navigates between views?

"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",

Sample code between home page and graph page.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    console.log('construct again');
  }

  showMigrationChart() {
    this.navCtrl.push(MigrationChart);
  }

  showColumnChart() {
    this.navCtrl.push(ColumnChart);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'migration-chart',
  templateUrl: '../../common/chart.html'
})
export class MigrationChart implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('appChart') private chartContainer: ElementRef;
  public chartName = 'Column Chart';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    console.log('MigrationChart construct again');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chartName = migrationEngine(this.chartContainer.nativeElement);
  }

  public onBackClick() {
    console.log('getViews length= '+ this.navCtrl.length());
    console.log('getViews = ', this.navCtrl.getViews());
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try changing root page instead of push/pop? Try and compare results. There are definitely known issues like yours on angulars github:/

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with Ionic framework.
On closing of page/component, there were no proper clean up of javascript timers and while loop which was causing app to slow down.
We changed code to do cleanup inside ngOnDestroy and everything work fine now.